# Angular with aspnet core - What is the difference between [HttpGet] and [HttpGet("[action]")?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

`[HttpGet]` seems to be applied to the appropriate controller methods by default in the autogenerated controllers in Visual Studio. But the api calls from Angular fail (this is an Angular 6 aspnet core 2.x app) with 400 error if I don't change them to `[HttpGet("[action]")`.

What is the difference between the two (I tried to [read the MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#token-replacement-in-route-templates-controller-action-area) but still unclear)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public IActionResult Action()
```

is equivalent to

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("[action]")]
public IActionResult Action()
```

So the difference is that `[HttpGet]` requires empty route part to match this action and `[HttpGet("[action]")]` requires action name to match the action. For instance

```cs
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet] 
    public IActionResult List() { }
}
```

Request to `/Products` will hit `List` action because resulting route is calculated by concatenating controller and action `[Route]` values (and joining them with `/`). In this example it is `"[controller]" + "" = "[controller]"`. In this example

```cs
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public IActionResult List() { }
}
```

In this case request to `/Products/List` will hit appropriate action because resulting url is calculated as following, `"[controller]" + "[action]" = "[controller]/[action]"`.